# Order by item from list inside list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

i have list of items of following class:

```
public class MonthlyConsumption : UserData
{
    public string Unit { get; set; }

    public List<DailyConsumption> DailyConsumptions { get; set; }
}

public class DailyConsumption
{
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }
    public double? Value { get; set; }
}
```

so as you can see, i have list of items where each item has also list of days inside.

My question is how can I order my main list by specyfic element inside inner list.

Example: I have list of type MonthlyConsumption. Each element of that list has collection of type DailyConsumption, and this collection is has day 10 days from January this year. How can I order my main list by 1 of Jan?

**Update**:
I am afraid i put my problem in wrong words, what i really want to do is to order my list of type MonthlyConsumption where each item has his own list of type DailyConsumption **by Value at specific Day** so if each item in my list has 10 days in his inner collection from jan 1 till 10, i want to ordery my main list by value in jan 1.

**Update**
I tried

```
return monthlyConsumption.OrderBy(x => x.DailyConsumptions.Where(y => y.Day.Day == 1))
                         .ToList();
```

but it gives me At least one object must implement `IComparable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, maybe something like this is what you are after:

```
var targetDay = DateTime.Now; //set to Jan 1st
var result =
    monthylConsumptions.OrderBy(
        x =>
        x.DailyConsumptions.Where(y => y.Day.Date == targetDay.Date).Select(z => (!z.Value.HasValue ? 0 : z.Value.Value)).SingleOrDefault());
```

"targetDay" should be set to Jan 1st, per your example.

This will sort ascending, by Value on the day you specify, and consider the default value  whenever there isn't one in that specific monthly.

**EDIT:**
I just tested the following unit test, and it passes, without showing the error you are describing:

```
[TestFixture]
public class LinqSortTest
{
    public class MonthlyConsumption
    {
        public string Unit { get; set; }

        public List<DailyConsumption> DailyConsumptions { get; set; }
    }

    public class DailyConsumption
    {
        public DateTime Day { get; set; }
        public double? Value { get; set; }
    }

    [Test]
    public void SomeTest()
    {
        var targetDay = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
        var monthlyConsumptions = new List<MonthlyConsumption>();
        monthlyConsumptions.Add(new MonthlyConsumption
            {
                Unit = "first",
                DailyConsumptions = new List<DailyConsumption>
                    {
                                new DailyConsumption { Day = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1), Value = 5 },
                                new DailyConsumption { Day = new DateTime(2013, 1, 5), Value = 100 }
                    }
            });
        monthlyConsumptions.Add(
            new MonthlyConsumption
                {
                    Unit = "second",
                    DailyConsumptions =
                        new List<DailyConsumption>
                            {
                                new DailyConsumption { Day = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1), Value = 2 },
                                new DailyConsumption { Day = new DateTime(2013, 1, 5), Value = 1 }
                            }
                });

        var result =
            monthlyConsumptions.OrderBy(
                x =>
                x.DailyConsumptions.Where(y => y.Day.Date == targetDay.Date).Select(
                    z => (!z.Value.HasValue ? 0 : z.Value.Value)).SingleOrDefault()).ToList();

        Assert.AreEqual("second", result[0].Unit);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `Assert` confirms that indeed the second item was placed first, because the Jan 1st value for "second" was lower than on "first".

Comment: well, i thought this way too, so i could even write  monthylConsumptions.OrderBy(x => x.DailyConsumptions.where(y=>y.DayDay==1)) but in mine and your case i have this error: At least one object must implement IComparable

Comment: I think that might be related to Value being a Nullable<T>

Comment: I just changed it a bit. Give that one a shot.

Comment: I changed even my class from double? to double, so there are not null and the problem is the same: At least one object must implement IComparable

Comment: Just edited my answer, adding a unit test that shows it working. Not sure about the cause of your error.

Comment: Indeed it works, problem was with double? , which surprisse me cos i tried to change to be not nullable and put there 0 if null, but any way u really helped me, and seems it didn't need to create custom IComperable, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tested it, but I believe you can do it with Linq.

Assume that "monthlyConsumptions" is a `List<MonthlyConsumption>`.

```
monthlyConsumptions.OrderBy(mc => mc.DailyConsumptions.Min(dc => dc.Day));
```

This will order your list of `MonthlyConsumption`s by their earliest `DailyConsumption`.

Comment: I am afraid i put my problem in wrong words, see please edit part in my post.

Comment: +1 - thank you jeremy, i had such an issue with orderby, followed by thenby on such a simple property, your 'min` pointed me in the right direction. this was due to deep hierarchical linq structures!! however, i will now forever know how to tackle them -cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
monthlyConsumptions
    .SelectMany(mc => mc.DailyConsumptions)
    .Where(dc = > dc.Day.Date.Day == 1 && dc.Day.Date.Month == 1)
    .OrderBy(dc => dc.Value)
    .Select(dc => dc.MonthlyConsumption);
```

This will get all `DailyConsumptions` for all `MonthlyConsumptions`, then filter only those from 1st of Jan, order them by `Value` and instead of getting any data from it, it returns parent entity which is `MonthlyConsumption`.

So you get `IQuerable<MonthlyConsumption>` ordered as you wished.

EDIT: That will work in LINQ to Entities, in your case probably not unfortunately, unless you have parent property in `DailyConsumption` called `MonthlyConsumption`.